# Get Guilds: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: discord

I'm working on a web app that uses Discord to sign and I was hoping to be able to pull the user's guild information once signed. I've already gone through the Authorization code grant process and have successfully retrieved the user's Access Token (Bearer). The Access Token has the 'identity' and 'guild' scope. When trying to retrieve the guild using the endpoint I get a 401 'unauthorized' error. I'm including the Bearer Access Token in the header of the request.

Endpoint: GET/guilds/{guild.id}

I'm unable to see what I'm missing/doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

[Postman Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuMTK.png)

Comment: post your code at least

Comment: Hey @Benjamin, no code yet, I'm just working with the HTTP endpoints via Postman. The attached screen shot shows the "failing" request.
Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guilds OAuth scope is not described to give access to the `GET /guilds/{guild.id}` route. The scope only seems to give access to `GET /users/@me/guilds`, which returns limited information.

```
{
    "id": "80351110224678912",
    "name": "1337 Krew",
    "icon": "8342729096ea3675442027381ff50dfe",
    "owner": true,
    "permissions": 36953089
}
```

https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sry, what's the right scope to use to get guild information of a guild where the current user (user's Access Token Bearer) is owner ?

Comment: @CrazyGreenHand Were you ever able to get data such as if the user was owner/moderator etc. I'm working on the same thing atm but in php